# How to boot from USB on Dell Latitude Win 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb

I bought a new Dell machine.

I have my old laptop HD in an external SATA to USB case, connected to the USB port.

I want to boot from that HD.

Attached is the BIOS setting of the Dell machine.
I read that I need to add boot option.
Can anybody please explain what exactly to do?
[image]

Comment: “I read that I need to add boot option.” – You don’t.

Comment: @DanielB OK. so what do i need to do?

Comment: @Moab if you can answer, not comment, i can mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the usb plugged in, power up the PC and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> when you see the dell logo, this should get you a boot device options screen, from this screen select your boot device, you may have to disable hibernation in W10 before trying this.

Answer (score 4):

To load from USB on Dell Latitude...

Go to BIOS (F2):

1. Go to Secure Boot and disable Secure Boot
2. Go to Advanced Boot Options and Enable Legacy Option ROMs
3. Go to UEFI Boot Path Security and set Always

Restart PC and go to boot menu (F12):

1. Select your USB device

Comment: This was really helpful...

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for opening an old thread.
I recently had this issue attempting to reimage a brand new SSD.

I found that by disabling the windows boot manager, allowing the computer to find no boot device, then rebooting and pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> caused the laptop to force detection of the USB. From there I was able to deploy an image successfully.

Answer (score 1):

The more recent Dell's don't have an option in the BIOS to boot into Legacy Mode, but if you create a bootable USB with UEFI support, you can press F12 at startup and your external USB should be detected.

You can download Rufus from here:     https://rufus.ie/

Make sure the option for UEFI is enabled when creating the bootable USB